# umbraco 7 how to access radio button list selected vaule in macro partial view

Tags: radiobuttonlist

I want access radio button list value in macro partial view in Umbraco7.4.3 
i have tried

```
  GetPropertyValue<Boolean>("active")
```

from [enter link description here](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Using-Umbraco/Backoffice-Overview/Property-Editors/Built-in-Property-Editors/Radiobutton-List)

in this i get every time true value. but i want result true if option one is selected and false for option two . or can i get selected options value ?

Answer (score 8):

First get the id of the individually selected radio button:

```
var SelectionId = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<Int32>("nameOfRadioButtonProperty");
```

This will return an integer for the specific radio button item that is selected. It will be a random id generated by Umbraco, e.g. 1209. This is why you find yourself with a value of true.

Then, if you need the name/value of the label for the selected radio button use this:

```
RadioTextValue = umbraco.library.GetPreValueAsString(SelectionId);
```

E.g. the returned value will be "active" (or whatever the text label is for the selected radio button, by way of it's int id).

Then you can do conditional checks using the meaningful text value rather than the random Umbraco id value.

Hope that helps and I understood your question correctly...

Comment: Thanks for this, Umbraco should have a more intuitive API for this really.